# React - how to display all products using dropdown?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

First time trying to do this so please bear with me.

I'm using a dropdown to filter product data from a local JSON file based on category. The code below does filter and display the products based on category when a user selects a category. However I'd like to show all of the products on load before the user selects a category. Currently it just shows a blank page, until a user clicks a category and then it filters and shows products.

Here's the filter code:

```
// Load in global state
  const { data, isLoading } = useAPI();

  const [selectedCategory, setSelectedCategory] = useState("All");

  const filteredCategories = data.filter(
    (machine) =>
      machine.category.toLowerCase() === selectedCategory.toLowerCase()
  );
```

The JSON is [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/yo4it?file=/public/db.json).

Dropdown code:

```
<div className="options">
   {!isLoading ? (
   <>
   <select
      value={selectedCategory}
      onChange={(e) =>
      setSelectedCategory(e.target.value)}
      className="product-dropdown"
      name="product-dropdown"
      >
      <option value="">All</option>
      {data.map((item) => (
      <option value={item.category}>{item.category}</option>
      ))}
   </select>
   </>
   ) : (
   <p>Loading...</p>
   )}
</div>
```

Lastly the code to render out the products:

```
export default function MachineList({ filteredCategories, filteredSearch }) {
  return (
    <>
      {filteredCategories.map((item) => (
        <ul>
          {/* Filter and map through the second level of API */}
          <div className="row">
            {item.product_details.filter(filteredSearch).map((subItem) => (
              <MachineCard
                image={subItem.image}
                title={subItem.model}
                weight={subItem.operating_weight}
                power={subItem.power}
              />
            ))}
          </div>
        </ul>
      ))}
    </>
  );
}
```

Any idea how I can show all of the products on load?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you filter based on whether the category of a product from `db.json` is equal to the `selectedCategory` state `toLowerCase`.

The reason this is a problem here is because it doesn't account for the fact that `'All'` isn't a category in your data. The `filter` call will always filter out all your data when `selectedCategory` is equal to `'All'`.

You want `'All'` to mean: Don't filter the data.

You can achieve this by changing your filter logic to something like this:

```
let filteredCategories = data;
if (selectedCategory !== "All") {
  filteredCategories = data.filter(
    (machine) =>
      machine.category.toLowerCase() === selectedCategory.toLowerCase()
  );
}
```

---

Also in your select:

```
<select
  value={selectedCategory}
  onChange={(e) => setSelectedCategory(e.target.value)}
  className="product-dropdown"
  name="product-dropdown"
>
  <option value="">All</option>
  {data.map((item) => (
    <option value={item.category}>{item.category}</option>
  ))}
</select>
```

change:

```
<option value="">All</option>
```

to:

```
<option value="All">All</option>
```

Since you pass `e.target.value` to `setSelectedCategory`, if you select an option other than `'All'` and select the `'All'` option after, it will cause your `selectedCategory` state to be set to an empty string. The `if` statement in the above filter logic doesn't account for this. So change the option `value` prop to `'All'` or add an extra condition to the `if` statement. I recommend the former.